# Node Javascript requiring additional identifier for use

Tags: javascript, node.js

Hey I am trying to use the pokeAPI from this resource https://pokeapi.co/docsv2/

```
let Pokedex = require('pokedex-promise-v2');
let Poke = new Pokedex();
```

but then to use it instead of being able to use `Poke.WhateverFunctionHonestly`

I need to use `Poke["pokedex-promise-v2"].WhateverFunctionHonestly`

Why is that and how can I use it just like `Poke.WhateverFunctionHonestly`

Comment: `let Poke = new Pokedex()['pokedex-promise-v2"]` ?

Comment: Thanks works as expected now, just wondering why in this case I have to add it like this, while normally it is no problem

Answer (score 0):

Use can try like that

```
let Pokedex = require('pokedex-promise-v2');
let Poke = {};
Poke["pokedex-promise-v2"] = new Pokedex()
Poke["pokedex-promise-v2"].getPokemonByName('eevee') // with Promise
.then(function (response) {
    console.log(response);
})
.catch(function (error) {
    console.log('There was an ERROR: ', error);
});
```